# C# HttpClient Deserialize Json Response Content - How to Select Key Value

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I'm trying to access the value of a Json key based on the value of another key via an API using `HttpClient` request.

My code is getting back the Json from the API but I'm not successful with targeting the specific key and getting back that data.

There is a key called `iso_1366_1` that lists a country code (US, AU, GB, etc) that includes a key called `certification`. I'm trying to return only the value of the certification key if the value of `iso_1366_1 == "US"`. When I execute the code, the value for `Rating` is `null`.

```cs
public static async Task getHttpApi()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/54597/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("release_dates?api_key=key");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result)!;
                        
                        var Rating = dynamicObject.certification;

                        if (dynamicObject.iso_3166_1 == "US")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Rating);
                        }
                           
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
        //return "";
    }
```

Here is the Json that is returned as the response object:

```json
{"id":54597,"results":[{"iso_3166_1":"FR","release_dates":[{"certification":"","descriptors":[],"iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"2011-09-19T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]},{"iso_3166_1":"NL","release_dates":[{"certification":"16","descriptors":[],"iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"2011-07-21T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]},{"iso_3166_1":"US","release_dates":[{"certification":"R","descriptors":[],"iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"2011-04-26T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]},{"iso_3166_1":"AU","release_dates":[{"certification":"R18+","descriptors":[],"iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"2011-04-25T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]},{"iso_3166_1":"GB","release_dates":[{"certification":"18","descriptors":[],"iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"2011-09-26T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]},{"iso_3166_1":"DE","release_dates":[{"certification":"18","descriptors":[],"iso_639_1":"de","note":"","release_date":"2011-09-19T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]}]}
```

I didn't clean up the json content since I wanted you to see what I'm seeing in my results.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use dynamic untill you know what do you need it for. Dynamic just another syntax for a dictionary, and it works even slower since it has an extra layer. In this case you can try LINQ to Json

```
    string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    JArray results = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["results"];

     var Rating = (string)results
                        .Where(x => (string)x["iso_3166_1"] == "US")
                        .SelectMany(x => x["release_dates"]
                        .Select(y => y["certification"]))
                        .FirstOrDefault(); // "R"
```

or longer way

```
    var usCertification = results.Where(x => (string)x["iso_3166_1"] == "US")
                        .SelectMany(x => x["release_dates"])
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (usCertification != null)
    {
        string Rating = (string)usCertification["certification"]; // "R"

        Console.WriteLine(Rating);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your help! Good advice about using dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is not what your code is trying to access:

[image]

I don't know how JSON.NET parses dynamic but you need to access the array element before accessing the property. It should be something like:

```cs
dynamicObject.results[0].iso_3166_1
```

Next time you should paste your JSON into a JSON editor (even as simple as your browser Javascript console) and make sure your JSON is correct.